# Is there a way to link mex file against code compiled without -fPIC

Tags: matlab, octave, mex

I am trying to wrap some C code to access it with Matlab/Octave. The problem is that the code has not been compiled with -fPIC, which seems to be necessary to wrap it with mex files. I don't have access to all of the source code so recompiling with -fPIC is no option. Is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't think there is. You may have to build a standalone executable and use the "system" command to run that.

Answer (score 2):

The -fPIC switch generates  position-independent code suitable for use in a shared library. If you have code generated without -fPIC, it isn't position-independent, and can't be used in a shared library. Since MEX-files are shared libraries, you won't be able to use non-PIC code in them.